# Plaid INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Tags: plaid

Trying to integrate, Stripe and Plaid with Firebase as my backend server.
I'm sure this isn't the best set up.

I'm getting my public_token and account_id from Plaids Link swift framework (Linkkit)

in my cloud code I have this function running.

```
plaidClient.exchangePublicToken(plaidData.public_token, function(err, res) {
        var accessToken = res.access_token;
        // Generate a bank account token
        plaidClient.createStripeToken(accessToken, plaidData.account_id, function(err, res) {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(res)
            var bankAccountToken = res.stripe_bank_account_token;
        });

    });
```

I get an access_token, public_token and account_id but the createStripeToken function keeps returning an INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.

What I've tried so far:

- Check Plaid status
- Checked to make sure my info.plist had env:
  sandbox
- Made sure to use sandbox institutions

What am I missing?